# How to delete a slice

Tags: mysql, django

Is there a way to do the following in django?

```
Catalog.objects.all()[:10000].delete()
```

If I try and delete all at one time, it raises a `TimeoutError`, and if I try and iterate all to delete each object at a time, it takes forever.

Comment: why delete by slice ? are u counting that slice may be returns different instances each time u apply it ?

Comment: @levi -- imagine I have a billion items and I want to delete them all (without being able to truncate table). I don't care what instances are deleted, as I want them all eventually deleted.

Comment: I think the best option, is using raw sql.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want something like this:

```python
batch_size = 10000
max_id = Catalog.objects.order_by('-id')[0].id
for start in range(0, max_id, batch_size):
    end = min(start + batch_size, max_id)
    Catalog.objects.filter(pk__gte=start, pk__lte=end).delete()
```

Comment: is the same as OP says,  you are iterating over them and deleting it.  OP tried that.

Comment: @levi That's batch deleting 10000 records at one query. OP tried deleting objects one by one.